# Vue reloads/sends XHR request every time key is pressed in text field

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have a text field for entering a description, but every time I press a key this appears and the page is reloaded:

```
XHR finished loading: PATCH "http://localhost:3000/ccenter/attachments/51".
```

I thought the way to tackle this is to set some sort of Timeout for the Value to be set, but I'm very new to JS and haven't figured out the best way to do this and would appreciate any pointers in the correct direction.

What I've tried, which is throwing me the error:

```
[Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: Setter must be a function: 3"

attachmentAccepted: {
  get: function () {
    return !this.attachment.ignoreAttachment;
  },
  set: setTimeout(function (val) {
    return this.updateAttachment([this.attachment.id, { ignoreAttachment: !val }]);
  }, 3000)
},
```

EDIT: This removes the reload, but then provides this error, which then stops the value of my Textinput being registered:

```
set: function (val) { setTimeout(function(){ return this.updateAttachment([this.attachment.id, { strValue: val }]) }, 3000)  },


 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'id')
```

EDIT 2: Solved.

```
set: function (val) { let self = this; setTimeout(function(){ /* your code goes here. change all 'this.' to 'self.' */ }, 3000)  }
```

Comment: Have you tried this: `set: function (val) { setTimeout(function(){ /* your code goes here */ }, 3000)  }` ?

Comment: @FarisHan thanks for your answer, I tried it (attached results in my edit).

Comment: Try this one: `set: function (val) { let self = this; setTimeout(function(){ /* your code goes here. change all 'this.' to 'self.' */ }, 3000)  }`

Comment: This worked! Thanks, I guess I got to research what you just did there.

Comment: You could use arrow function instead `setTimeout(() => {}, 3000) `. Then `this.updateAttachment` should work.

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR

Replace

```
set: setTimeout(function (val) {
  return this.updateAttachment([this.attachment.id, { ignoreAttachment: !val }]);
}, 3000)
```

with

```
set: function (val) {
  let self = this;
  setTimeout(function(){
    self.updateAttachment([self.attachment.id, { ignoreAttachment: !val }]); 
  }, 3000)
}
```

---

`[Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: Setter must be a function: 3"` means `set:`  property of `attachmentAccepted` must be a function. Something like `set: function(){}`.

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'id')` means the program cannot read `.id` of an object. In this case, `this.attachment` object is undefined, so you cannot do `this.attachment.id`.

`this.attachment` is undefined because,

```
set: function /* <<< SCOPE A function declaration */ (val) {
  
  /* "this" right here is a thing that referring to SCOPE A, and... */
  console.log(this)

  setTimeout(function() /* <<< SCOPE B function declaration */ {
    
    /* ... "this" right here is another thing that referring to SCOPE B. 
      And because of the same name, SCOPE A's "this" cannot be used anymore. */
    console.log(this)

    return this.updateAttachment([this.attachment.id, { strValue: val }])
  }, 3000)
}
```

So just pass SCOPE A's `this` to SCOPE B. One of the solution is using `var self = this;` inside SCOPE A. Now you can use SCOPE A's `this` inside SCOPE B with the `self` variable.

```
set: function /* SCOPE A */ (val) {
  let self = this;
  setTimeout(function /* SCOPE B */ (){
    self.updateAttachment([self.attachment.id, { ignoreAttachment: !val }]); 
  }, 3000)
}

// OR

set: function /* SCOPE A */ (val) {
  let SCOPE_A_THIS = this;
  setTimeout(function /* SCOPE B */ (){
    SCOPE_A_THIS.updateAttachment([SCOPE_A_THIS.attachment.id, { ignoreAttachment: !val }]); 
  }, 3000)
}
```

Bonus: [Understanding "this" in javascript with arrow functions](https://www.codementor.io/@dariogarciamoya/understanding-this-in-javascript-with-arrow-functions-gcpjwfyuc)